# Angular Ionic dark mode toggle

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

How can I make a toggle where the user can choose:

**Light | Dark | Auto**

where light or dark is the appearance of the PWA and 'Auto' follows system dark/light mode.

I have tried following the docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode but even doing `document.body.classList.toggle('dark', false);` on `ngOnInit` in a component does not work, thanks!

Edit:
So far I've tried:

```
  mode = 'auto';
  prefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  constructor() {
    this.prefersDark.addEventListener('change', (e) => console.log(e));
  }

  setMode = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const storeMode = this.mode;

    await Storage.set({
      key: 'keep',
      value: storeMode
    });
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark', true);
  };

  checkAwake = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const { value } = await Storage.get({ key: 'keep' });
    if (value) {
      this.mode = value;
    }
  };
```

but nothing happens, the class does have a 'dark' appended when `setMode` is called but nothing changes. The variables SCSS files are unchanged from when the project is initialised from ionic start.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<ion-item lines="full">
  <ion-icon slot="start" name="moon"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>
    Toggle Dark Theme
  </ion-label>
  <ion-toggle id="themeToggle" slot="end"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

**CSS**

```
body.dark {
  --ion-color-primary: #428cff;
  --ion-color-primary-rgb: 66, 140, 255;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-primary-shade: #3a7be0;
  --ion-color-primary-tint: #5598ff;

  --ion-color-secondary: #50c8ff;
  --ion-color-secondary-rgb: 80, 200, 255;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-secondary-shade: #46b0e0;
  --ion-color-secondary-tint: #62ceff;

  --ion-color-tertiary: #6a64ff;
  --ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 106, 100, 255;
  --ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-tertiary-shade: #5d58e0;
  --ion-color-tertiary-tint: #7974ff;

  --ion-color-success: #2fdf75;
  --ion-color-success-rgb: 47, 223, 117;
  --ion-color-success-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --ion-color-success-shade: #29c467;
  --ion-color-success-tint: #44e283;

  --ion-color-warning: #ffd534;
  --ion-color-warning-rgb: 255, 213, 52;
  --ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --ion-color-warning-shade: #e0bb2e;
  --ion-color-warning-tint: #ffd948;

  --ion-color-danger: #ff4961;
  --ion-color-danger-rgb: 255, 73, 97;
  --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-danger-shade: #e04055;
  --ion-color-danger-tint: #ff5b71;

  --ion-color-dark: #f4f5f8;
  --ion-color-dark-rgb: 244, 245, 248;
  --ion-color-dark-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-dark-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --ion-color-dark-shade: #d7d8da;
  --ion-color-dark-tint: #f5f6f9;

  --ion-color-medium: #989aa2;
  --ion-color-medium-rgb: 152, 154, 162;
  --ion-color-medium-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --ion-color-medium-shade: #86888f;
  --ion-color-medium-tint: #a2a4ab;

  --ion-color-light: #222428;
  --ion-color-light-rgb: 34, 36, 40;
  --ion-color-light-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-light-shade: #1e2023;
  --ion-color-light-tint: #383a3e;
}

/*
 * iOS Dark Theme
 * -------------------
 */

.ios body.dark {
  --ion-background-color: #000000;
  --ion-background-color-rgb: 0, 0, 0;

  --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
  --ion-text-color-rgb: 255, 255, 255;

  --ion-color-step-50: #0d0d0d;
  --ion-color-step-100: #1a1a1a;
  --ion-color-step-150: #262626;
  --ion-color-step-200: #333333;
  --ion-color-step-250: #404040;
  --ion-color-step-300: #4d4d4d;
  --ion-color-step-350: #595959;
  --ion-color-step-400: #666666;
  --ion-color-step-450: #737373;
  --ion-color-step-500: #808080;
  --ion-color-step-550: #8c8c8c;
  --ion-color-step-600: #999999;
  --ion-color-step-650: #a6a6a6;
  --ion-color-step-700: #b3b3b3;
  --ion-color-step-750: #bfbfbf;
  --ion-color-step-800: #cccccc;
  --ion-color-step-850: #d9d9d9;
  --ion-color-step-900: #e6e6e6;
  --ion-color-step-950: #f2f2f2;

  --ion-toolbar-background: #0d0d0d;

  --ion-item-background: #1c1c1c;
  --ion-item-background-activated: #313131;
}

/*
 * Material Design Dark Theme
 * ------------------------------
 */

.md body.dark {
  --ion-background-color: #121212;
  --ion-background-color-rgb: 18, 18, 18;

  --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
  --ion-text-color-rgb: 255, 255, 255;

  --ion-border-color: #222222;

  --ion-color-step-50: #1e1e1e;
  --ion-color-step-100: #2a2a2a;
  --ion-color-step-150: #363636;
  --ion-color-step-200: #414141;
  --ion-color-step-250: #4d4d4d;
  --ion-color-step-300: #595959;
  --ion-color-step-350: #656565;
  --ion-color-step-400: #717171;
  --ion-color-step-450: #7d7d7d;
  --ion-color-step-500: #898989;
  --ion-color-step-550: #949494;
  --ion-color-step-600: #a0a0a0;
  --ion-color-step-650: #acacac;
  --ion-color-step-700: #b8b8b8;
  --ion-color-step-750: #c4c4c4;
  --ion-color-step-800: #d0d0d0;
  --ion-color-step-850: #dbdbdb;
  --ion-color-step-900: #e7e7e7;
  --ion-color-step-950: #f3f3f3;

  --ion-item-background: #1a1b1e;
}

/* Optional CSS, this is added for the flashing that happens when toggling between themes */
ion-item {
  --transition: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
toggle.addEventListener('ionChange', (ev) => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark', ev.detail.checked);
});

const prefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

// Listen for changes to the prefers-color-scheme media query
prefersDark.addListener((e) => checkToggle(e.matches));

// Called when the app loads
function loadApp() {
  checkToggle(prefersDark.matches);
}

// Called by the media query to check/uncheck the toggle
function checkToggle(shouldCheck) {
  toggle.checked = shouldCheck;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Only thing is, ` document.body.classList.toggle('dark', ev.detail.checked);` adds the 'dark' class on the body tag, but nothing happens?

Comment: @DuncanLaw There is an open issue about toggling the dark mode manually
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/issues/1335